# webpack with icomoon does not work

Tags: fonts, compilation, icons, webpack, assets

T try to compile generated fonts by icomoon with webpack, but with the following webpack config does not get executed. I'm using url-loader and file-loader to generate output but the test are failing at the end

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    path = require('path');



const sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
]

const config = {
    entry: {

        app: ['./js/app']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!autoprefixer-loader")
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            },

            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/icon-woff" }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        publicPath: '/bundles/build/'
    },
    amd: {jQuery: true},
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        //new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)
    ],
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            magnificPopup: 'node_modules/maginific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js' //JQuery Plugin
        },

        modulesDirectories: ['./js', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass'],
        root: [path.join(__dirname, './')]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

I add the font as is shown here

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:    url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?9ht85s');
    src:    url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?9ht85s#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?9ht85s') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?9ht85s') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?9ht85s#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

so is complaining becuase of suffixes, I remove suffixes getting compiled but no font shows

when I run weppack -w I get

```
ERROR in ./fonts/icomoon.ttf?9ht85s
Module parse failed: fonts\icomoon.ttf?9ht85s Unexpected character
' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the solution :)

Your regex is not matching the font url of your `@font-face`. So it's another loader which tries to parse your font files.

Change your loader with this regex, it should work:

```
{
  test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
  loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
}, {
  test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
  loader: "file-loader"
}
```

Comment: thanks this one is working fine now I have to combine somehow the regex to match font awsome icons as well

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work for me" check if the regex matches the uri of your font file. The above regex does not for example include # and other characters after the ?

Answer (score 2):

@Finrod gave a good answer, but the file URI has to match the regex in order for the file to be processed by the rule.

As an example, using IcoMoon fonts, and some of the URIs above do not work, because the font-face block is as follows:

```js
@font-face {
  font-family: 'connectlab';
  src:  url("../fonts/icomoon.eot?9ht85s");
  src:  url("../fonts/icomoon.eot?9ht85s#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  url("../fonts/icomoon.ttf?9ht85s") format('truetype'),
  url("../fonts/icomoon.woff?9ht85s") format('woff'),
  url("../fonts/icomoon.svg?9ht85s#icomoon") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Note that the regex specified above will fail on all the paths containing a #

```
// fail
test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)?(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/

// better ??
test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
```